# Pandas transform with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

The code below make a groupby and then replaces all values below 3 with na and then use the last value instead.

However, for ID 11, the first observation in group B get the value 9 using this method, the last value of group A. This is not desirable. This happens because the mask returns NaN when True and the ffill() doesn't take the groupby into consideration.

Is there a smart way to solve this, to replace values below 3 with the last value, and, when the first value of a group is below 3, use another method, perhaps x.mean() to replace.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list(range(1,21)),
             'group':['A']*10 + ['B']*10,
            'value':[4,6,2,9,7,5,1,9,8, 9, np.nan, 4,5,6,1,2,3,4,2,6]
             })

data.groupby('group').transform(lambda x: x.mask(x < 3)).ffill()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ffill` in lambda function and replace first missing values by `mean`:

```
data['value'] = (data.groupby('group')['value']
                     .transform(lambda x: x.mask(x < 3).ffill().fillna(x.mean())))
print (data)

    ID group     value
0    1     A  4.000000
1    2     A  6.000000
2    3     A  6.000000
3    4     A  9.000000
4    5     A  7.000000
5    6     A  5.000000
6    7     A  5.000000
7    8     A  9.000000
8    9     A  8.000000
9   10     A  9.000000
10  11     B  3.666667
11  12     B  4.000000
12  13     B  5.000000
13  14     B  6.000000
14  15     B  6.000000
15  16     B  6.000000
16  17     B  3.000000
17  18     B  4.000000
18  19     B  4.000000
19  20     B  6.000000
```

---

```
s = data.groupby('group')['value'].transform('mean')
data['value']=data['value'].mask(data['value'] < 3).groupby(data['group']).ffill().fillna(s)
print (data)
    ID group     value
0    1     A  4.000000
1    2     A  6.000000
2    3     A  6.000000
3    4     A  9.000000
4    5     A  7.000000
5    6     A  5.000000
6    7     A  5.000000
7    8     A  9.000000
8    9     A  8.000000
9   10     A  9.000000
10  11     B  3.666667
11  12     B  4.000000
12  13     B  5.000000
13  14     B  6.000000
14  15     B  6.000000
15  16     B  6.000000
16  17     B  3.000000
17  18     B  4.000000
18  19     B  4.000000
19  20     B  6.000000
```

Comment: great solution. However, if I want to expliclty stae that this replacement with mean should only be applicable for the first value of a group - is that doable?

Comment: @Henri - hmmm, if large dataframe and few NaNs then it should be used.